# Error Compiling IOS and React Native Causing Swift Error

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I have a problem running my react native app in IOS. `The following build commands failed: SwiftCompile normal x86_64 Compiling\ STPAPIClient+ApplePay.swift,\ STPAPIClient+PaymentsCore.swift,\ STPApplePayContext.swift /` ........

I just updated my xcode to the latest version

Full Error

```
/Users/joe/Documents/play/test_app/ios/TestApp.xcodeproj: warning: Multiple targets match implicit dependency for linker flag '-lOGReactNativeWaveform'. Consider adding an explicit dependency on the intended target to resolve this ambiguity. (in target 'TestApp' from project 'TestApp')
    note: Target 'OGReactNativeWaveform' (in project 'Pods')
    note: Target 'OGReactNativeWaveform' (in project 'OGReactNativeWaveform')
warning: Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'TestApp' from project 'TestApp')
warning: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'TestApp' from project 'TestApp')
warning: Run script build phase 'Start Packager' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'TestApp' from project 'TestApp')
warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] [RNFB] Core Configuration' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'TestApp' from project 'TestApp')
warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] [RNFB] Crashlytics Configuration' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'TestApp' from project 'TestApp')


    The following build commands failed:
            SwiftCompile normal x86_64 Compiling\ STPAPIClient+ApplePay.swift,\ STPAPIClient+PaymentsCore.swift,\ STPApplePayContext.swift /Users/joe/Documents/play/test_app/ios/Pods/StripeApplePay/StripeApplePay/StripeApplePay/Source/ApplePayContext/STPAPIClient+ApplePay.swift /Users/joe/Documents/play/test_app/ios/Pods/StripeApplePay/StripeApplePay/StripeApplePay/Source/PaymentsCore/Categories/STPAPIClient+PaymentsCore.swift /Users/joe/Documents/play/test_app/ios/Pods/StripeApplePay/StripeApplePay/StripeApplePay/Source/ApplePayContext/STPApplePayContext.swift (in target 'StripeApplePay' from project 'Pods')
            CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/joe/Documents/play/test_app/ios/Pods/StripeApplePay/StripeApplePay/StripeApplePay/Source/ApplePayContext/STPApplePayContext.swift (in target 'StripeApplePay' from project 'Pods')
    (2 failures)
```

Comment: it does not mention the error at all. Run with `--stacktrace` option to get the stack trace. Run with `--info` or `--debug` option to get more log output

Comment: @Raptor. There are lots but its kinda like the same as what I posted above. anyway I added more

Comment: Are there any codes that we can reproduce the same error?